# Command-line C & keyboard shortcut (in Mac OS)

Tags: c, macos, keyboard, shortcut

How can I execute a command when user press a key in a command-line C application? Is it possible when window isn't focused

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the program itself, you could do either of those:

1. [block on unbuffered getc](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) you get the key strokes as they come and not when users hits return.
2. create some sort of event loop, using select/epoll or event framework like ([libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)/[libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)) and get a callback whenever a user hits a key.
3. use a toolkit like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) which provides a pseudo graphical command line interface and an event loop.
4. if the keys you're interesting in capturing are things like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you need signal handlers.